# Extract labels from dataframe

Tags: r

I am trying to extract the labels of some variables in a dataframe in R. The columns contain the variable name and a label underneath (in Danish), which looks like this:

[image]

I have tried to run the code below:

```
names<-names(data)
```

However, as seen below this gives the names and not the labels, which is what I need.

[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the `sjlabelled` package and built in data set `efc` as an example

```
library(sjlabelled)
data(efc)
labels <- as.list(get_label(efc))
```

Discussed in further detail [here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/sjlabelled/vignettes/labelleddata.html)

Answer (score 2):

You can apply `attr(x,"label")` to multiple columns.

```
vars_labels = sapply(mydataframe,
       function(x){attr(x,"label")})
```

Since `vars_labels` is a vector and doesn't looks friendly for human, it can be converted to dataframe:

```
vars_labels = data.frame(vars=names(vars_labels), labels=vars_labels, row.names = NULL)
```

Answer (score -1):

Another approach from R base, just unlisting.

```
unlist(labels(data))
```